# Trying to add a little bit of data to a table i'm getting an error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to add a couple of data to a table this code

```
INSERT INTO MegaPlan(Plan_Name, Quota, Price)
VALUES ('Budget Plan', '2GB + 1GB', '$29.95'),
       ('Netlover Broadband', '15GB + 15GB', '$49.95'),
       ('ADSL2+ Basic','5GB + 2GB','$39.95'),
       ('Xtreme ADSL2+','30GB + 30GB','$69.95'),
       ('Freedom Light','3GB + 2GB','$39.95'),
       ('Freedom Heavy','20GB + 10GB','$79.95')
```

This the table which i'm trying to add data to

```
CREATE TABLE MegaPlan 
(
    Plan_Name VARCHAR Primary Key,
    Quota VARCHAR(15),
    Price int,
    AccessID int,
    FOREIGN KEY (AccessID) REFERENCES Access(AccessID)
)
```

Error I'm getting is

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

The statement has been terminated.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Although trying to insert *strings* like `$29.95` into an integer will throw conversion errors

Comment: I'm terribly sorry error i'm getting is Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. When creating a table, if you define just `varchar` (as for your `Plan_Name`), then it defaults to ***1 character*** in length - typically **not** what you're looking for!

Comment: `Price int` is the wrongest thing i ever saw in a Table

Comment: @Simo I agree that is pretty awful but it isn't even the worst thing in the table posted.

Comment: @simo i'm sorry still trying to get the hang of this

Comment: @SeanLange the table on its own has no problem, the problem is that a _price value_ is saved inside an `Integer` instead of a`double` or a `decimal`. Oh, and the `varchar`

Comment: @Simo varchar with no length, Quota stored as a string (this probably needs some calculations at some point to see if they are within the quota). Those are just a couple of other pretty big issues here. What I am getting at is that price as an int is by far not even close to the "wrongest thing" ever in a table.

Comment: @SeanLange it is if you try to put a string inside it

Comment: I didn't add a value to the column plan_name because before adding a value I needed to check.

Answer (score 0):

`Price` has `INT` type, so you can't insert the price with `$` prefix & other thing is that `Plan_Name` has `VARCHAR` which means it has only 1 `char` length. You need to alter table to modify the length of `Plan_Name`:

```
alter table MegaPlan
     alter Plan_Name varchar(255) not null
```

And, then i try to insert the data

```
INSERT INTO MegaPlan(Plan_Name, Quota, Price)
VALUES ('Budget Plan', '2GB + 1GB', 29.95),
       ('Netlover Broadband', '15GB + 15GB', 49.95),
       ('ADSL2+ Basic','5GB + 2GB', 39.95),
       ('Xtreme ADSL2+','30GB + 30GB', 69.95),
       ('Freedom Light','3GB + 2GB', 39.95),
       ('Freedom Heavy','20GB + 10GB', 79.95)
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can add the $ sign ?

Comment: @Firephantom19 `29.95` isn't an integer either

Comment: I just noticed it I guess I should change it to a float

Comment: NOT float, decimal.

Comment: The $-sign should not be stored in the DB, but instead be a matter of formatting when displaying the price.

Answer (score 0):

Price is int, and you are trying to assign string to it. 
Try to make the Price VARCHAR instead of INT